# Leaflet - Layers and sub layers

Tags: leaflet

I want a Leaflet layer control which when checked/unchecked must display/hide all the sublayers inside the main layer. I also want to check/uncheck the sublayers independently. I looked through Leaflet docs and forums but couldn't find any reference for this. Should I write a custom control for this? Please advise.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you are going to need to have to write a custom control for this, as `L.Control.Layers` does not have nesting support built in currently.

Answer (score 0):

You can try using `LayerGroup`. From official documentation:

> **LayerGroup**
>
> Used to group several layers and handle them as one. If you add it to
>   the map, any layers added or removed from the group will be
>   added/removed on the map as well. Extends Layer.
>
> Usage example
>
> ```
> L.layerGroup([marker1, marker2])
>     .addLayer(polyline)
>     .addTo(map);
> ```